# why two aliases to "array of string" treated differently?

Tags: delphi, generics

In Pascal there are two kinds of type declarations:

- type aliases: *type NewName = OldType*
- type creation: *type NewType = **type** OldType*

The former is just creating convenient shorthand, like *typedef* in C. The aliases are compatible one to another and to their original type. The created types are intentionally incompatible and cannot be mixed without explicit and unsafe by definition typecast.

```
var
  nn: NewName; nt: NewType; ot: OldType;
...
  nn := ot; // should work
  nt := ot; // should break with type safety violation error.

  nt := NewType(ot); // Disabling type safety. Should work even if 
  // it has no sense semantically and types really ARE incompatible.
```

Those are Pascal basics as i understand them.

Now let's look at one certain type and two its aliases:

- System.Types.TStringDynArray = **array of** string;
- System.TArray<T> = **array of** T;

  - *in particular that means* TArray<string> = **array of** string; *by definition.*

Now let's take function returning the former type alias and feed its result to the function expecting the latter one:

```
uses Classes, IOUtils;

 TStringList.Create.AddStrings(
    TDirectory.GetFiles('c:\', '*.dll') );

 TStringList.Create.AddStrings(
     TArray<string>( // this is required by compiler - but why ???
         TDirectory.GetFiles('c:\', '*.dll') ) );
```

1st snippet would not compile due to types violation.
2nd one happily compiles and works, but is fragile towards future type changes and is redundant.

QC tells that compiler is right and the RTL design is wrong.
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=106246

WHY compiler is right here ?
Why those aliases are incompatible ?
Even the very manner RTL was designed suggests that they were deemed compatible!

PS. David suggested even simplier example, without using TArray<T>

```
 type T1 = array of string; T2 = array of string;

 procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  function Generator: T1;
    begin Result := T1.Create('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'); end;
  procedure Consumer (const data: T2);
    begin
      with TStringList.Create do 
      try
        AddStrings(data);
        Self.Caption := CommaText;
      finally
        Free;
      end;
    end;
  begin
    Consumer(Generator);
  end;
```

Same gotcha without explanation...

PPS. There are a number of doc refs now. I want to stress one thing: while this restriction might be indirectly inherited from Pascal Report of 1949, today is 2012 and Delphi used very differently from school labs of half-century ago.
I named few BAD effects of keeping this restrictions, and yet did not saw any good one.

Ironic thing, that this restricion may be lifted without breaking rules of Pascal: in Pascal there is no such non-strict beast as Open Arrays and Dynamic Arrays. So let those original fixed arrays be restricted as they wish, but Open Arrays and Dynamic Arrays are not Pascal citizens and are not obliged to be limited by its codebook!

Please, communicate Emba in QC or maybe even here, but if u just pass by without expressing your opinion - nothing would change!

Comment: No need to bring generics into this. Try `type T1 = array of string; T2 = array of string` and then attempt to assign a variable of type T1 to one of type T2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key to understanding this issue is the [Type Compatibility and Identity](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity) topic in the language guide. I suggest you have a good read of that topic.

It is also helpful to simplify the example. The inclusion of generics in the example serves mainly to complicate and confuse matters.

```
program TypeCompatibilityAndIdentity;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TInteger1 = Integer;
  TInteger2 = Integer;
  TArray1 = array of Integer;
  TArray2 = array of Integer;
  TArray3 = TArray1;

var
  Integer1: TInteger1;
  Integer2: TInteger2;
  Array1: TArray1;
  Array2: TArray2;
  Array3: TArray3;

begin
  Integer1 := Integer2; // no error here
  Array1 := Array2; // E2010 Incompatible types: 'TArray1' and 'TArray2'
  Array1 := Array3; // no error here
end.
```

From the documentation:

> When one type identifier is declared using another type identifier, without qualification, they denote the same type.

This means that `TInteger1` and `TInteger2` are the **same** type, and are indeed the same type as `Integer`.

A little further on in the documentation is this:

> Language constructions that function as type names denote a different type each time they occur.

The declarations of `TArray1` and `TArray2` fall into this category. And that means that these two identifiers denote different types.

Now we need to look at the section discussing compatibility. This gives a set of rules to follow to determine whether or not two types are compatible or assignment compatible. We can in fact shortcut that discussion by referring to another help topic: [Structured Types, Array Types and Assignments](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Array_Types_and_Assignments) which states clearly:

> Arrays are assignment-compatible only if they are of the same type.

This makes it clear why the assignment `Array1 := Array2` results in a compiler error.

Your code looked at passing parameters, but mine focused on assignment. The issues are the same because, as the [Calling Procedures and Functions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Calling_Procedures_and_Functions#Program_Control_and_Parameters) help topic explains:

> When calling a routine, remember that:
>
> - expressions used to pass typed const and value parameters must be assignment-compatible with the corresponding formal parameters.
> - .......

Comment: *Every type is compatible with itself. Two distinct types are compatible if they satisfy at least one of the following conditions.* -and loooong list of special cases. What it basically means ? That restrictions of either vanilla school Pascal or early limited Turbo compiler now hampers the composability of real programs. Yes, those types are formally different, but they are practically compatible. The example claims *create two distinct types, TS1 and TS2.* but then it claims they are *compatible*. What is it ? It is practical denying of formal constructs. Arrays should be compatible as well!

Comment: And no, i care little about firect `var1 := var2`. It has little practical sense (for most of times). You might need `var1 := expression-with-var2`, but what are expressions with records and arrays ? they are some kind of functions. MapReduce and such. So i care about ease of chaining functions, about laconic expressive source. Assignment between vars would not help me much, but when i need to add a lot of boilerplate just to combine two standard functions - it is kinda hidden rooks on the running track!

Comment: "And no, i care little about firect var1 := var2". Why not? Passing parameters to a procedure is pretty much the same as assigning to a variable. And so assignment-compatibility is the nub of the issue here. It's precisely what your question is all about. Re-write my example code in terms of parameter passing if you prefer, the conclusions are exactly the same. Does this not answer your question? I know it's frustrating for you, but the rules are the rules and we can't change them. Only Emba can change them.

Comment: *Passing parameters to a procedure is pretty much* yes, in the same sense as programming in Delphi is thesame as programming in assembler. All Turing-complete languages are merely syntax sugar for each other. But in really i do not use direct non-mutating assignment much. It just has little practical sense. But i do call one functions wrt result of another. If compiler treats it like assignin - be it, it is its internal choice. I care about compatibility = composability of expressions and functions.

Comment: *Only Emba can change them.* and we can raise the question. We can ask 'hello! Delphi is out of infancy! type to move on!' And the fact that Emba made a mistake in its RTL just a good time to raise the voice. Like anti-MSIE comments in microsoft sites, this case higlights that this legacy restriction lost any practical sense and only hamper productivity. Emba RTL architects - the most informed and experienced - failed to account for that restriction. If that does not show how dumb that restriction is novadays, then i do not know what can be.

Comment: The documentation links I provided explain the rules that the compiler follows. Why those rules are so quite possibly date back to the birth of Pascal.

Comment: yes, i yesterday glanced through "Pascal Report" of 1949/1974, and that rule suits there fine. No such thing like "open array",  u can not make `procedure xxx(list yy: array of byte)`; everything must have name. And u only right small snippets like bubble sort for your school work, no other's code, now your own code from yesterday year, so yes, u could plan AL the datatypes. In 1949 you could. But today it is just inconsistency.

Comment: There's no point complaining to me. It's Emba that you need to talk to. Changing `TStringDynArray = TArray<string>` as Stefan suggests would appear to be the easy way out for them.

Comment: i did, i opened QC ticket, and i am trying to get community attention too. Yet no one pointed any good effect of this restrictin. May we all ask Emba to change this ? systematically change like they did with Open Array, not patch it one type after another. I asked them, feel free to join QC and express your opinion!

Answer (score 7):

Delphi is a strongly typed language. That means that identical (in this case I mean their definitions look exactly the same) types are not assignment compatible.

When you write `array of <type>` you are defining a type and not an alias. As David already said in his comment the two identical types like

```
type 
  T1 = array of string; 
  T2 = array of string;
```

are not assignment compatible.

Same goes for

```
type
  TStringDynArray = array of string;
  TArray<T> = array of string;
```

Often people forget about the incompatibility of identical types and my guess would be that they did when they introduced IOUtils for example. Theoretically the definition of TStringDynArray should have been changed to `TStringDynArray = TArray<string>` but I guess that could have raised other problems (not saying bugs with generics...).

Comment: Oookay, so you do `TStringDynArray = TArray<T>` - and why they became assignment-compatible out of the blue ? if "identical types are not assignment compatible" this definition should change NOTHING.

Why do we have `Windows.DWORD = System.Types.DWORD;` and `System.Types.DWORD = System.LongWord;` and expect them to be compatible ?
And what is the sense in `type X = type Y ` construction left ?
By "other problems" u mean backward compatibility with libraries made for prior versions of Delphi ? Like TStrings extension did not accounted for IOUtils or vice versa ? Unneeded type alienation did it!

Comment: @Arioch'The: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant `TStringDynArray = TArray<string>`.

Comment: @Arioch: `type X = type Y` creates a new RTTI for X. So you can find out if you have a TMyString or TYourString with both "= type string". Simple types are assignment-compatible. But an array is a complex ("constructed") type like a record.

Comment: TStringDynArray = TArray<string> would change nothing

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, it would because there will be only one `TArray<string>` type in your application. Define `T1 = TArray<string>` and `T2 = TArray<string>` and see that variables of each type are assignment compatible. If that would not be the case whole Generics.Collections.pas would not compile.

Comment: Yes, I see that is so now. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overloads_and_Type_Compatibility_in_Generics) says "Two instantiated generics are considered assignment compatible if the base types are identical (or are aliases to a common type) and the type arguments are identical."

Comment: That might had sense in TurboPascal, where (1) all arrays had fixed length, (2) u could only return simple types from functions. For what i remember, constructed types could not be assigned at all, compiler did not knew how to do it. So you had to use var-parameters and unioque type aliases. But now there is no technical sense in that, compiler is not that limited now. And that unneeded restriction seriously damages program composition flexibility. This is legacy from ancient compiler and today there is no good in that legacy!

Comment: `T1 = TArray<string> and T2 = TArray<string>` are compatible. `T1 = Array of string and T2 = Array of string` are not. And `Array of string = TArray<string>`. Doesn't it feel like schizophrenia ?

Comment: @Arioch If you define two different types even if they look the same there is some reason you do so. And that is why they are not compatible to each other. If you want them to be compatible then use one type instead of 2. There is a reason behind it. If it were like you wish: today both types are the same and the program just compiles fine and works. Tomorrow one of the 2 types gets changed and boom nothing compiles anymore.

Comment: Let's look at the issue from one more angle. What is the reason d'etre for TArray<T> if it is incompatible to all the inherited code ? Maybe Delphi would better define `type array of T = TArray<T>` instead ? Now as soon as u use TArray<T> it turns to be islated, incompatible with all prior code. And then what is the value of in that type ? Use old good dynamic arrays and you're done.

Comment: *If you define two different types even if they look the same there is some reason you do so.* - that is exactly that mentioned `type TFileName = type string` construct. When i use simple `type` - i do not *define different types*. Delphi does, leaving me no choice. *If you want them to be compatible then use one type instead of 2* Even Embarcadero itself failed to do it. How do you imagine all the community from different landsand years would do it ? Come on! we still don't have One True Include with IfDef's for compiler versions. Each library has and mantain it's own. Such simple thing!

Comment: Now u deem practical to make kinda Grand Unified Type System ? Without migrating to CLR/JVM ? With support for libraries and compilers few years back and forth ?

Comment: *Tomorrow one of the 2 types gets changed and boom nothing compiles anymore* Yes, yes, exactly! But it is worse! You force me to use explicit typecasts where  there is no need for them. So tomorrow, when one type changes - it would compile - but would not work. Delphi enforces developer to disable typification! Or you might call this gently 'override'. And when tomorrow types would really run incompatible - the developer would get kind of PAnsiChar(UnicodeString), that would compile fine, but would not work.

Comment: yeah, i smell the same. I define an alias to some type, and you claim i was intending to isolate those type. I was not, don't say what is not so! But you  just left me without choice.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem with Delphi, where I wanted to pass values from one identical array to another. Not only did I have "incompatibility" problems with two like array assignments, but I also could not use the **"Copy()"** procedure. To get around this problem, I found that I could use a pointer to an **type** array of array of string, instead.

For example:

```
type RecArry = array of array of string
     end;
var TArryPtr : ^RecArry;
```

Now, I can pass the values from any fixed array to another identical array without any compatibility or function problems. For example:

```
TArryPtr := @RecArry.LstArray //This works!
TArryPtr := @LstArray         //This also works!
```

With this created array assignment template, I can now work with all two dimensional arrays without any problems. However, it should be understood, that when accessing this type of string array pointer, an extra element is created, so that when we would expect this type of array 2D array below, for example:

```
Two_Dimensional_Fixed_Array[10][0]
```

We now get an extra element adjusted array as seen here:

```
New_Two_Dimensional_Fixed_Array[10][1]
```

This means that we have to use some slightly tricky code to access the pointer array, because all the populated elements in Two_Dimensional_Fixed_Array[10][0] have moved down, so that they are offset by 1, as in New_Two_Dimensional_Fixed_Array[10][1].

Therefore where we would normally find the value **'X'** in Two_Dimensional_Fixed_Array**[1][0]**, it will now be found here in TArryPtr**[0][1]**.

Its a trade off we all have to live with!

Another important note to bear in mind is the definition of a pointer array when it is declared. When a pointer array is type declared, the Borland compiler will not allow the Pointer array to have the same element size as the array to which it is pointing too. For example, if an array is declared as:

`Orig_Arry : array [1..50,1] of string;`

The pointer array which should point to it would be declared in the following fashion:

`Type Pntr_Arry : array [1..50,2] of string;`

Did you notice the the extra element? I am guessing the the Borland compiler has to widen the array pointer to allow for the pointer address.