# What I should change in this Delphi code, to get the right result?

Tags: delphi, debugging

In this Delphi code, should be store the minmum value into **newA** and delete it from **A** , this repeated until **A** reached to the **size 0**

```
type TDoubleDynArray  = array of Double;

          ..............

            ..........
```

//Get minimum value:

```
function MinValue(var minPos : Integer; Data: TDoubleDynArray): Double;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ShowMessageUser(IntToStr( Length(data)));
  Result := Data[Low(Data)];
  for I := Low(Data) + 1 to High(Data) do
    if Result > Data[I] then
      minPos := i;

  Result := Data[minPos];
end;
```

//-------------------------Main function ------------------

```
function TForm1.Func(X: TDoubleDynArray): Double;
var
A, newA : TDoubleDynArray;
i, minPos : Integer;
begin

   SetLength(A, 55);
   SetLength(newA, 55);
   A := Copy(X,0, 55);


      for i := 0 to 54 do
      begin
        newA[i] := MinValue(MinPos,A);
        Delete(A, MinPos, 1);
      end;

           ..............

            ..........


 end;
```

When i run the code it stop on size 3 (length of A = 3):

The Result of function MinValue()
//ShowMessageUser(IntToStr( Length(data)));

55
54
53
52
51
50
49
48
47
46
45
44
43
42
41
40
39
38
37
36
35
34
33
32
31
30
29
28
27
26
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
3
3

What I should change to get the right result (length(A) := 0)???

Comment: Just set `minPos` value in `MinValue` function to `Low(Data)` at first line :) P.S. have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: MinValue has multiple errors. However you should throw away all of the code and just sort the array with a decent sort algo. Your selection sort is O(n^2). Delphi has built in functions to sort.

Comment: Desired result could be provided with simple sorting

Comment: @David Heffernan, what is the name of built in function??

Comment: [`TArray.Sort`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Sort)

Comment: @David, I'd have assumed that implementing selection sort was the *purpose* of this student's exercise (perhaps as a precursor to implementing a better algorithm and observing the differences).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous problems with your code. Most obviously, `MinValue` is badly broken. It fails to set `minPos` when the first value in the array is the lowest. That explains why your code fails.

However, you should probably remove all of the code and use the built in sorting functions. Your hand rolled selection sort doesn't work (yet) and even when fixed will still be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Use [`TArray.Sort`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Sort) to perform the sort.

```
var
  SortedX: TArray<Double>;
....
SortedX := Copy(X, 0, 55);
TArray.Sort<Double>(SortedX);
```

This uses Quicksort which has a time complexity of O(n log n) on average.

Even if your version of Delphi predates `TArray.Sort`, conceptually you should be using a well proven sort algorithm, encapsulated cleanly. Don't roll your own ad-hoc sorting code inline like this.

---

As a minor aside, it's pointless to create a new array, and then throw it away as you do in this code:

```
SetLength(A, 55);
A := Copy(X, 0, 55);
```

The call to `SetLength` is pointless and wasteful because the newly created array is thrown away when replaced by the new array returned by `Copy`.

Comment: how can I choose the type of sorting (descending or ascending)

Comment: Pass a custom comparer to `Sort`, see the doc link

Comment: what if I want to use this type 
var
  SortedX: TDoubleDynArray

Comment: I have got this error Undeclared identifier: 'TArray'

Comment: The easiest way is to call `TComparer.Construct`

Comment: Do bear in mind that I don't know what delphi version you use. If it's a modern version you should use the generic dyn array `TArray<T>` for type compatibility reasons. If you don't have generics then you should use a general sort code suited to whateve delphi version you have.

Comment: Yes, you should do that everywhere so that your code is more flexible and composable

Comment: @David. Off topic: On my Delphi (XE3) Delete()'s help only notes strings and not dynamic arrays. Online help does note dynamic arrays. When was it expanded to dynamic arrays?

Comment: @ David Heffernan can I do like this :

uses

 .............

type TDoubleDynArray  = TArray<double>;

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Blurry XE8 I think. If I'd been cleverer I could have used that to infer asker's version.

Comment: You don't need to use the generic array if you don't want to. But there are advantages of doing so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14383278/505088

Comment: @David Heffernan I have changed all to TArray<double>; but why I get this error : Undeclared identifier: 'TArray'

Comment: You'll encounter that with `TArray.Sort` unless you include the unit which declares `TArray`. Which is documented in the link I provided. It's `System.Generics.Collections`.

Comment: @David Heffernan what about multidimensional Array how can I use "TArray<double>" in this case?

Comment: `TArray<TArray<Double>>`

Comment: @David Heffernan Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the MinValue function..

From what I can see you want to get the lowest value in the array. Currently you are only getting the last element in the array of lower value than the first element in the array irrespective of whether it is the lowest value in the total array. That happens because you keep on comparing to the Result which was set to the first element of the array and it never gets updated.

The code below gives back the lowest value in the array.

```
function MinValue(var minPos : Integer; Data: TDoubleDynArray): Double;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  minPos := 0;

  for I := 1 to High(Data) do
    if Data[I] < Data[minPos] then
      minPos := I;

  Result := Data[minPos];
end;
```

Comment: No, what I want is take the lowest value from A and put it in another array, then delete it from A, and keep doing this until the length of A = 0

Comment: @shdotcom You cannot take the lowest value with wrong MinValue function

Comment: This should set minPos to -1 if the array has length 0 I think

Comment: @David. Agreed. If he keeps using it in the for loop as he is now then it will not be needed. But it is always a good idea to do the preventative code aspecially if he changes the calling code.