# How to work with Generic methods and parameter array of array of < T >?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-10.1-berlin

A lot of times when working with generic arrays I need to know Max length of the arrays I'm working with. For a longtime I was using:

```
MaxIntValue([Length(Array1), Length(Array2) , Length(Array3)]); // from Math unit
```

Then I simplified this (to skip typing Length()) with my method:

```
// array of array of TCardBrand
function GetMaxLength(const aArrays: array of TArrayOfCarBrand): integer;
```

Works good, but now I want to create a generic MaxLength and I can't make it work with

```
class function MaxLength<T>(aArrays: array of array of T): integer; - it gives error: [dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(31): E2029 Identifier expected but 'ARRAY' found
```

Here is the code what I'm testing, with working example of MaxIntValue from Math unit and example of my method, but extending generic TArray doesn't work:

```
TCarBrand = record
    BrandID: integer;
    BrandName: string;
    BrandCountry: string;
  end;

  TArrayOfCarBrand = array of TCarBrand;

  TArray = class(System.Generics.Collections.TArray)
  public          
      // ERROR:  E2029 Identifier expected but 'ARRAY' found
       class function MaxLength<T>(aArrays: array of array of T): integer;
  end;

var  
  vCarsUS, vCarsEU, vCarsJP: TArrayOfCarBrand;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


class function TArray.MaxLength<T>(aArrays: array of array of T): integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := Low(aArrays) to High(aArrays) do
    Result := MaxIntValue([Result, Length(aArrays[i])]);
end;


function GetMaxLength(const aArrays: array of TArrayOfCarBrand): integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := Low(aArrays) to High(aArrays) do
    Result := MaxIntValue([Result, Length(aArrays[i])]);
end;


procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var vMaxLength: integer;
begin
  // test lengths
  SetLength(vCarsUS,1);
  SetLength(vCarsEU,10);
  SetLength(vCarsJP,100);

  // using MaxIntValue from Math unit - works OK
  vMaxLength := MaxIntValue([Length(vCarsUS), Length(vCarsEU), Length(vCarsJP)]);

  // using my method GetMaxLength - works OK
  vMaxLength := GetMaxLength([vCarsUS, vCarsEU, vCarsJP]);

  // trying to set Generic TArray.MaxLength - ERROR
  vMaxLength := TArray.MaxLength<TCarBrand>([vCarsUS, vCarsEU, vCarsJP]);
end;
```

**How can I extend generic MaxValue to accept open array of array of < T >?**

Comment: Can I ask why you persist with dynamic arrays rather than collection classes? You seem to be perpetuating a state of needless complexity.

Comment: I did look into it once and I use arrays too much to be just a simple definition change, like is change from `array of T` to `TArray<T>`, which is almost done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's simple enough. Your function does not accept generic arrays, because the parameter list does not attempt to do so. Change it like this.

```
class function MaxLength<T>(const aArrays: array of TArray<T>): Integer;
```

The key here is to use `TArray<T>` exclusively. This is the generic dynamic array type and using it gives more flexible type compatibility than with `array of` dynamic array types. The issues are covered in detail here: [What are the reasons to use TArray instead of Array of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14383278/505088)

A consequence of this is that you will need to replace all of your dynamic type declarations and use `TArray<T>` instead. In fact you don't need to declare any dynamic array types at all. You can remove all declarations of this form:

```
type
  TFooArray = array of TFoo;
```

And then replace all occurrences of `TFooArray` with `TArray<TFoo>`. A side benefit is that you don't need to declare any of the array types and your code becomes less verbose.

I would also comment that there's little point in using `MaxIntValue` when you only have two arguments. Use the `Max` function then.

Comment: This works great! Now I can pass 1-n number of arrays (as long as they are TArray<T>) and will get Max Length value. I also get sometimes confused do I need `Length` or `High` values, with this function there will be no confusion, now.