# Delphi TRichEdit to Array and local storage

Tags: arrays, delphi, storage, trichedit

I'm looking for informations on how to put TRichEdit into an Array and save it to Local file (ex: File.dat).
The goal is to store a number of text, with a description, and the 'name' of it.

I think I have to start with:

```
type
   TMessage = record
     Name : string;
     Desc : string;
     Text : TMemoryStream;
end;

var ARListMessages: array[1..50] of TMessage
```

And add data with something like:

```
richedit.Lines.SaveToStream( ARListMessages[i].Text );
```

- How to create the Array, and make manipulations on it (Add, remove
  ...) with the 'name'?
- How can I save it (Array), and load it easily from local storage ?    (Ex:
  File.dat)

I've found some informations [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/borland.public.delphi.vcl.components.using/QYouF-yb7BA/Dz9Kpu1EWFYJ), without beeing able to make something working.

Thanks for your time.

**[EDIT 18/09/2017]**

I'm Still looking to find a solution, and try to find a way to save my informations to a local file.

My actual code to test is :

```
var
  MessageArray  : array of TMessage;

// // // //

  SetLength(MessageArray, 1);
  MessageArray[0].Name := 'Hey You';
  MessageArray[0].Desc := 'Im here and will stay here, just in case';
  MessageArray[0].Text := TMemoryStream.Create;
  MessageArray[0].Text.Position := 0;
  RichEdit1.plaintext := false;
  RichEdit1.Lines.SaveToStream( MessageArray[0].Text );
```

So, looking to save *MessageArray*, but haven't find how to do that yet.
I've take a look on [SuperObjet](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject), but can't find how to deal with it.
Omxl was looking Great and easy, but free trial ... :(

Comment: A fixed length array is automatically created.

Comment: ? Sorry, i don't undersand.

Comment: You asked how to allocate the array. You don't. It is allocated automatically. On the other hand it might be better to use a dynamic array. Then you allocate with SetLength.

Comment: In addition to what @DavidHeffernan said, you can't use `String` in your record, `String` is one of the data types that require a finalization, and as such, they can not be stored in a File type

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i've a little edited my post, but i was thinking i was easy to do ... 
So, what can be my alternative of String ? (Convert it to Json ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create the Array, and make manipulations on it (Add, remove
>   ...) with the 'name'?

From your first code the array is already created. No further work is needed. And even if you use dynamic arrays you still don't have to do any thing just declaring it will suffice.

If you are asking "*How to create the array ?*" as in "*How to create such a list, so I could add, remove with the 'name' field*" then I would suggest [TDictionary](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/Generics_Collections_TDictionary_(Delphi)) (instead of the city names use your field 'name' as a key) to do the manipulations and then when saving [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397996/tdictionary-save-to-file)

> How can I save it (Array), and load it easily from local storage ?
>   (Ex: File.dat)

You can't directly just like `array.savetofile;`.You need to use one of file handling methods like [TFileStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TFileStream) to [store the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373418/how-can-i-save-a-dynamic-array-to-a-filestream-in-delphi).

**Note:** in your edit the memory stream will cause you only trouble because each time you create it you will need to free it after its use instead use these functions to extract formatted text and change the field `Text : TMemoryStream;` to `Text : string;`

1. `RichTextToStr`: Convert the rich format text to a `string`.

   ```
   function RichTextToStr(RichEdit:TRichEdit):string;
   var
   SS : TStringStream;
   begin
   SS := TStringStream.Create('');
     try
     RichEdit.Lines.SaveToStream(SS);
     Result := SS.DataString;
     finally
     SS.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```
2. `loadToRichedit`: Load the formatted text to the `RichEdit` again.

   ```
   procedure loadToRichedit(Const St:string;RichEdit:TRichEdit);
   var
   SS : TStringStream;
   begin
   SS := TStringStream.Create(St);
      try
      RichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(SS);
      finally
      SS.Free;
      end;
   end;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to have an answer.
I share it here if someone need the solution.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections, Classes, System.Zip;


type
  TPersonne = class
  strict private
     FNom   : string;
     FPrenom: string;
  public
    property Nom:    string read FNom    write FNom;
    property Prenom: string read FPrenom write FPrenom;
  end;

  TFamille = class(TDictionary<string, TPersonne>)
  private
    procedure LoadFromStream(stream: TStream);
    procedure SaveToStream(stream: TStream);
  public
    procedure LoadFromFile(const AFileName: string);
    procedure SaveToFile(const AFileName: string);
  end;

procedure TFamille.SaveToStream(stream: TStream);
var
   i: Integer;
   Personne: TPersonne;
   Pair: System.Generics.Collections.TPair<string, TPersonne>;
   Writer: TWriter;
begin
   Writer := TWriter.Create(stream, 4096);
   try
      Writer.WriteListBegin;
      for Pair in Self do
      begin
         Writer.WriteString(Pair.Key);
         Writer.WriteListBegin;

         Personne := Pair.Value;

         Writer.WriteString(Personne.Nom);
         Writer.WriteString(Personne.Prenom);

         Writer.WriteListEnd;
      end;
      Writer.WriteListEnd;
   finally
      Writer.Free;
   end;
end;

procedure TFamille.LoadFromStream(stream: TStream);
var
   Personne: TPersonne;
   Reader: TReader;
   sKey: string;
begin
   Clear;
   Reader := TReader.Create(stream, 1024);
   try
      Reader.ReadListBegin;
      while not Reader.EndOfList do
      begin
         sKey     := Reader.ReadString;
         Personne := TPersonne.Create;

         Reader.ReadListBegin;

         while not Reader.EndOfList do
         begin
            Personne.Nom    := Reader.ReadString;
            Personne.Prenom := Reader.ReadString;
         end;

         Reader.ReadListEnd;
         Add(sKey, Personne);
      end;
      Reader.ReadListEnd;
   finally
      Reader.Free;
   end;
end;

procedure TFamille.LoadFromFile(const AFileName: string);
var
   Stream: TStream;
begin
   Stream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead);
   try
      LoadFromStream(Stream);
   finally
      Stream.Free;
   end;
end;

procedure TFamille.SaveToFile(const AFileName: string);
var
   stream: TStream;
begin
   stream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmCreate);
   try
      SaveToStream(stream);
   finally
      stream.Free;
   end;
end;

var
   Famille:  TFamille;
   Personne: TPersonne;
begin
   try
      Famille := TFamille.Create;
      try
         Personne := TPersonne.Create;
         Personne.Nom    := 'Julie';
         Personne.Prenom := 'Albertine';

         Famille.Add('1', Personne);

         Famille.SaveToFile('D:\famille.txt');

      finally
         FreeAndNil(Famille);
      end;

      Famille := TFamille.Create;
      try
         Famille.LoadFromFile('D:\famille.txt');

         if Famille.Count > 0 then
            Writeln(Famille['1'].Nom + ' ' + Famille['1'].Prenom);
      finally
         FreeAndNil(Famille);
      end;

      Readln;
   except
   on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
   end;
end.
```

Thanks all for your Help !

Comment: good to see that you made it your self, if my answer gave you the what you needed to solve your problem. Would you consider to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)